# Rails has many through - getting value from intervening model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have three models in a has many through association, that basically connects users to accounts via memberships like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  has_many :memberships
  has_many :accounts, :through => :memberships    
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :expiration_date, :name, :status, :url

  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, :through => :memberships

  has_one  :owner, :class_name => "Membership", :conditions => ["role = ?", "Owner"]
  has_many :admins, :class_name => "Membership", :conditions => ["role = ?", "Admin"]
  has_many :executives, :class_name => "Membership", :conditions => ["role = ? OR role = ?", "Owner", "Admin"]

end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :account_id, :user_id, :role

  validates :role, :uniqueness => { :scope => :account_id }, :if => "role == 'Owner'"

  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I want to be able to get users through the methods `Account.first.owner`, `Account.first.admins` and `Account.first.executives`. Obviously, as it is, I'm only getting memberships.

I could easily achieve that by defining new methods on my account model, using something like `self.memberships.find_by_role('Owner').user` and `self.memberships.find_all_by_role("Admin").collect {|u| u.user}`, but it seems more sloppy to me. Is there a way to do it purely through associations?

Any help is much appreciated, including to criticize my approach... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 3, you can accomplish this sort of thing really efficiently simply by defining your own methods. For example:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, :through => memberships

  def owner
    users.where(:role => 'Owner').first
  end

  def admins
    users.where(:role => 'Admin')
  end
end
```

This code can be used by simply calling `account.owner` or `account.admins`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I wish I could use this simple syntax on my custom methods, but role is an attribute of membership, not user, since the same user can have many accounts with different roles in them. But do you think there's any performance gain if I stick to associations or is it the same if I define custom methods?

Comment: All of Rails' ActiveRecord query interface is lazy. This means that it does not perform the query until you try to use it, and it will compress multiple chained mehtods into a single query. I will edit my answer with a proper solution to your question.